# C: dynamic sized 2d array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc, c-strings

I'm quite new to C and also confused by memory allocation for arrays and the fact that strings are stored as arrays of characters.

I want to create a 2d array of strings with *n* rows, 2 columns and variable sized string lengths. So it's structure would look like this.

```
char people = {
    {"name1..", "info.."},
    {"name2..", "info.."},
    {"name3..", "info.."},
}
```

I take *n* as user input so I know how many rows the array will have.

How would I define such an array using malloc and resize the space allocated for the strings while the user types using realloc.
Or is there a better way to store data like this in C?

I would like to be able to use it like:

```
printf("%s", people[0][0]);
prints: name1..

people[0][0][4] = 'E';
//Change the fifth letter of this element to for example E
```

I've tried quite a few things, but nothing I trie seems to work like I want it to.

Comment: A common use case [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamically+allocate+2d+array+of+string+in+C+site%3Astackoverflow.com) is. Please do some research. There are several ways to go. Decide for one, fail and come back with a (more) specific issue. You were welcome.

Comment: Use this if nothing works: people[n][2][128]. But usually it is structure and array of structures.

Answer (score 0):

Using pointer to pointer to `char *` you can achieve your requirements.

Consider below example as reference.

```
char ***arr; // to hold n*2 strings

int n =3;
arr = malloc(n*sizeof(char **));

int i = 0;
for (i =0;i<n;i++)
{
        arr[i] = malloc(2*sizeof (char *)); // to hold single row (2 strings)

        arr[i][0] = malloc(10); // to hold 1st string
        arr[i][1] = malloc(10); // to hold 2nd string

        strcpy(arr[i][0],"name");
        strcpy(arr[i][1],"info");

        arr[i][0][4] = 'E';    // As you wished to change particular char

        printf("%s %s", arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
        printf("\n");
}
```

And for resizing the particular string you can use `realloc` as below.

```
char *temp;
temp = realloc(arr[1][0], 100);

arr[1][0] = temp;
```

Disclaimer: I have not added any bound and error checks.

Comment: @nullp0tr Why it overflows only in `malloc` ?

Comment: I think this would be more clear with a `struct`; then you could store the allotted number of bytes for each string as well.

Comment: @kiran it doesn't overflow only in `malloc`, but the kind of bugs and security vulnerabilities you get from an overflow in `malloc` is more severe than in other situations.